# Android XMLPullParser multiple passes through XML document

Tags: android, traversal, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to use XMLPullParser to parse a large XML document for an Android application.  Often I need to re-traverse the document from the beginning.

1. How would I reset the parser?  It seems inefficient to call getResources.getXML() repeatedly.  What about calling calling setInput on the parser directly to reset?  Is there a code example.
2. If the xml document needs to be traversed multiple times, is XMLPullParser still recommended for performance concerns.

Regards

Comment: I have also the same question. I was thinking of using a singleton to parse the XML file. Haven't tried it yet, though.

Comment: Same question. Already spend 10 hours hacking code trying to solve this problem. This side of Android/Java is not so nicely crafted I would say.